# Does Castle ActiveRecord supports SQL formula?

Tags: nhibernate, castle-activerecord

Does Castle ActiveRecord supports SQL formula as supported by nHibernate?

E.g. In nHibernate we can do something like this.

```
<property name="CountOfPosts"
    formula="(select count(*) from Posts where Posts.Id = Id)"/>
```

Is this supported in Castle Active Record?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yup, the [[Property] attribute](http://web.archive.org/web/20110414071714/http://www.castleproject.org/activerecord/documentation/trunk/manual/attributedocs/Generated_PropertyAttribute.html#PropertyAttribute_Properties) has a Formula property.

```
[Property(Formula = "(select count(*) from Posts where Posts.Id = Id)")]
public int CountOfPosts {get;set;}
```